# electronjs - how can I get mac address of the machine

Tags: node.js, macos, networking

I am building a desktop app using electronjs.
I want to be able to identify a machine uniquely. I believe it should be ok to use mac address of the machine as unique identifier.
I don't know how to get mac address of the machine. Couldn't find any good example on internet.
Appreciate all the help.

Thank you.

Comment: Or perhaps this one: [get the mac address of the current machine with node.js using getmac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16386371/get-the-mac-address-of-the-current-machine-with-node-js-using-getmac)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am new to electronjs (and nodejs too), so this is main reason I find getting things done difficult. Thank you @Brettski for suggestions in the comments.
Following commands and script worked for me:

1. Installed getmac in my local electronjs project folder, by running this command.
   npm install --save getmac
2. In the JavaScript created getmac variable by importing getmac module
   const getmac = require('getmac')
3. Ready to use, by invoking it's default function:
   console.log(getmac.default())

   I couldn't successfully run getMAC() function, but default() worked. I guess, I need to understand what args to pass etc.